# Sytanx to execute command in pentaho kettle shell

Tags: postgresql, shell, command, pentaho, kettle

```
"CMD.EXE /C "  psql -h ipaddress -d dbname -u user -p password -c "\copy  table  to 'd:/bcptest/file.csv' with delimiter as '|'"
```

I have to execute this command in pentaho shell. But it is showing as parse error in script.  By this command i have to copy data from a postgres table which is remote and save as .csv file in local.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

- You do not have to write any code inside pentaho for transferring
  data.
- You just have to create sample transformation using spoon, which will
  have table input step create your database connection with the remote
  server.
- Then use text file output and store your result.

Understand the concept of ETL Tool before implementing anything.

Comment: I cannot use table input step and select rows since it takes a lot of time for data loading. At present i have the same step but it takes hours  to extract data from postgres and load in sqlserver as i have many tables. So I am looking for solution like bulk processing. So i must use copy command to extract data from postgresql.

Comment: Pentaho does provide bulk-load steps.. check whether bulkloading step for sqlserver is available or not.

Comment: Yes bulkloading for sql server is available but it needs text/csv file as input.